# Multiple email addresses on the same CC line in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

Is there any way to include multiple email addresses on the same CC (or To) line in Thunderbird?

It looks like for every recipient I have to start a new CC field below, which can be very tedious and take quite a bit of screen real state.

Answer (score 0):

Separating addresses with a semicolon seems to work.

Comment: Really? Not for me. Addresses don't autocomplete and the email address is shown in red (as when I type an email address that is not valid)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use comma, but this is unofficial feature.
Here is an explanation [at Mozilla Support site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1038045)